# Why gives error when I try insert an empty image in database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a small form on a webpage. The form has 3 fields: Name, age and image.

Everything is working correctly if all fields are filled. However if no input images gives this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEB\Request_1.php on line 98
```

Line 98 - `$image=  addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));`

```
Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\WEB\Request_1.php on line 100
```

Line 100 - `$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);`

I like that it‘s recorded in the database even if the file field was empty. 
I made a small change to write to the database if the file was empty and writes, but the error appears anyway.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $name = addslashes($_POST[name]); 
        $age = addslashes($_POST[age]); 
    }
    if (!isset($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) 
    {
        $insert2 = "INSERT INTO form (name, age) VALUES ('$name, '$age)";
        mysql_query($insert2);
    }
    else
    {
        $image=  addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
        $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $insert = "INSERT INTO form (name, age, image) VALUES (''$name, '$age, '$image')";
        mysql_query($insert);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
if (!isset($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))
```

with

```
if ( @$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] == '')
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if (!isset($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]))
```

to

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name']; 
  $age = $_POST['age'];
       $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
       $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
       $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
       $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];   
       $value = explode(".", $file_name);
       $file_ext = strtolower(array_pop($value));

      $expensions= array("png","jpg");   
      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)== false)
      {
       $errors="Extension not allowed, please choose a png or jpg file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 9097152)
      {
      $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }    
      if(empty($errors)==true)
      {
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"upload/".$file_name);
 $insert2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO form (name, age, image) VALUES (''$name, '$age', '$file_name')");
 echo "The file ".$file_name." has been uploaded.";
       //echo "Success";
      }
      else
      {
       print_r($errors);
      }
     }
```